# XAMPP no puede iniciar MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

Tengo que hacer unos cuantos ejercicios en php con bases de datos y durante probablemente más de 6 meses me ha funcionado perfectamente sin apenas ningún problema que pueda resolver por mi cuenta, como cambiar el puerto de 3306 a 3307 para que funcionara.

Recientemente empiezo a tener un problema y es que me denega el acceso siquiera al localhost.

[image: Acceso denegado al localhost]

Preguntando a profesores como solucionarlo me dicen que quizá es porque tengo otro servicio de MySQL paralelo y que trate de detenerlo para ver si funciona. Busqué el servicio, lo desactivé y ahora cada vez que trato de iniciar MySQL me pide permisos de administrador (net command) y, se los conceda o no, no funciona. Simplemente no carga, se queda así.

[image: XAMPP no puede iniciar MySQL]

Llevo más tiempo del que me gustaría tratando de resolver algo que no sé como hacerlo, y la ayuda que he encontrado en otros posts de poco me ha servido.

Comment: Claramente te muestra cual es el problema, lo que pasa es que tienes mal ingresada las credenciales de tu base de datos... revisa el archivo de configuración, en la parte donde tienes el usuario y la contraseña, también fíjate el puerto que usa.. por que en el panel muestra que el puerto 3306 esta en uso por ende no podrá usarlo mysql

Comment: Cierra todo. Ve a la carpeta de xampp, busca `xampp-control`. Has click derecho y ejecútalo como administrador. Donde dice `Modules Service` has click para activar Apache y MySQL, debes aceptar los permisos de red que te pida. Luego cliqueas en `Start` en ambos y listo. Reinicias la PC y apache correrá al iniciar.

Comment: El mensaje de error de XAMP dice que no se puede iniciar MySQL porque hay otro proceso usando el puerto 3306. Solo cambia el puerto y trata de iniciar el servicio nuevamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es más bien una actualización de mi problema con xampp y mysql, pero quiero que quede como solución.

Tiré la toalla hace unos meses ya que no tenía que usar siquiera mysql durante un tiempo, pero recientemente he tenido que volver a usarlo, así que de nuevo me he puesto a encontrar una solución. Modificar el cofig no ha servido de nada. El puerto que mysql utilizaba lo cambie varias veces sin solucion. No niego que eso sean las soluciones más comunes a ese problema, pero yo diría que en casos así la solución es esta:

1. Ejecutar xampp como administrador.
2. Comprobar que el servicio tenga un check. Si no lo tiene, darle click a la cruz, rodeada en rojo (sé que en mi caso esta funcionando), e instalar el servicio.
   [image: xampp]
3. En teoría debería estar todo. La única desventaja si se puede llamar es que va a pedirte permisos de administrador cada vez que se intente iniciar un servicio. Puede ser un poco molesto, pero mientras funcione no debería ser un inconveniente.

Espero que mi propia respuesta ayude a alguien más que tenga este mismo problema y no vea solución por ninguna parte.

Answer (score 2):

Esta anunciando que las credenciales de la base de datos sin incorrectas, revisa el archivo de configuración config.inc.php en la parte donde están las credenciales de la base de datos

```
$dbuser='yourDBUserName';
$dbpass='';
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpMyAdminDBName';
$dbserver='';
$dbport='';
$dbtype='mysql';
```

También debes revisar en la configuración  del MySql porque esta anunciando que el puerto 3306 esta ocupado, por ende no podrá levantar en ese puerto